# Solving $x^{\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor}\; =\; 2014$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> $x^{\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor}\; =\; 2014$

Mathematica gives that there are no solutions, but how do you actually come to the conclusion that there exists no solution to this equation?

Comment: An idea is to examine the discontinuities of the function in that region. So find a solution to $x^x=2014$ and inspect the values close to the decimal solution of x. There will be a skip from 2012 to 2015 or something to that extent.

Comment: Try $x$ slight less than and slightly more than 5.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I got it -- consider x = 4.9999...; then it is pretty much 5^4 which is 625. The next possible jump is x = 5 which give 3125. 2014 is between those but because there is no possible value of x between x = 4.9999... and x=5 there is no solution

Comment: Is this a problem that expects an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x < 0$.  Then the LHS will have a strictly negative integer exponent:  $\lfloor x \rfloor = k$, where $k \in \{ -1, -2, \ldots \}.$  Hence we would require $x = (2014)^{1/k}$, but this number is positive, so we arrive at a contradiction. Thus $x > 0$.

Indeed, we must have $x > 1$, for if $0 < x \le 1$, then the LHS is obviously $1$.  Now observe that because $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$, we must have $$x^{x-1} < x^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \le x^x.$$  Hence by direct calculation, we find $$4 < x < 5.$$  That is, $x = 4 + \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.  Then we have $$x^{\lfloor x \rfloor} = (4+\epsilon)^4.$$  If we require this to equal $2014$, then solving for $\epsilon$ immediately yields $$\epsilon = (2014)^{1/4} - 4 \approx 2.69908 \not\in (0,1),$$ hence no such solution exists.

Without calculating the numerical value of $\epsilon$, we can also easily determine that it exceeds $1$, for $2014 > 1296 = 6^4$, hence $(2014)^{1/4} > 6$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one way is to plot it, and you will see that the curve is discontinuous and jumps over 2014.

[image]

Of course this function is always increasing, so the discontinuity here is enough to show that there is no solution :)

Comment: See the graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^floor%28x%29%3D2014).

Comment: @Joel, edit your link!

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink, thanks.